# Intel HD Graphics not working after Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, 64-bit, intel-graphics

So I used to have a Windows 10 32-bit OS on a 64-bit processor laptop and then I decided to upgrade to 64-bit OS. So I did a clean install of Windows 10 64-bit and now my PC runs slower than it used to earlier because, for some reason, it is not using the Intel Graphic Card that is inbuilt. The Graphic Card is **Intel HD Graphics 4000**. In the device manager, under the Display Adapters, I can only see Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

I looked up a lot about this on the Internet and tried to install drivers for the GC. But when I downloaded the official 64-bit Win10 drivers from the Intel Website, it says it's not compatible with my system. To be sure, I even tried the 32-bit installer but still had no luck.

Please help!!!!!

*Note: I'm am not very knowledgeable at Computer systems so if I seem like an idiot, please point out my mistake.*

Comment: What make / model is the laptop? Have you tried getting drivers from the manufacturer?

Comment: @Smock The laptop is a Dell Latitude E6430. Processor -  Intel Core i5 3340M 2.70GHz. Yes, I did try to contact the manufacturer website but it is running very slow and I can't seem to be able to use it by any means.

Comment: Have you tried [this driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=kk9j0&oscode=wt64a&productcode=latitude-e6430) from Dell? (There's two older version on there you could also try)

Comment: Also consider the Intel Driver. Both 64-bit and 32-bit drivers are shown:  https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81499/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000

Comment: @John They've said in the OP that the Intel driver didn't work. (Assuming they got the right one)

Comment: I missed that. Sorry.  If none of the drivers work, your laptop may not be fully compatible. One thing to try is to remove the video driver (it will run in VGA) and then let Windows Update install its video driver from the Microsoft Catalogue.

Comment: Your driver page, for future reference>>>https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/indhs1/product-support/product/latitude-e6530/drivers